# Как сделать, если тег .text пустой то его родителю .container даётся стиль display: none;

Tags: html, css, display

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="text"></div>  
</div>
```

Я хотел сделать так:

```
.text:empty .container {   
  display: none;   
}
```

но вспомнил что родительным элементам не придаются стили, как поступить?

Comment: Без js никак, но есть 2 выхода: убирать пустой элемент на серверном языке, если нет контента `-или-` оформить элемент `.text`, убрав стили с `.container` совсем. Тогда, если `.text:empty` - у него новое оформление.

Comment: С помощью псевдокласса `:has`, вот так: `.container:has(.text:empty) { display: none; }`. Но у такого способа своя проблема - плохая поддержка браузеров (Псевдокласс `:has` начали поддерживать только с +- 100'ых версий браузеров).

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо

Comment: Офигеть, скоро js не нужен будет - всё будут делать на css))

Comment: @DavidMeyster не за что! Я всё же рекомендую вам использовать JavaScript, т.к. `:has` всё-таки до сих пор слишком свежий.

Comment: @NL993 , даже со 105+ версий, а FF ещё и под флагом. И, верно, что JS пока будет надёжнее.

Comment: мне кажется что разработчики css стремятся к тому что бы временем вытеснить javascript

Comment: @DavidMeyster , на будущее - старайтесь, чтобы дочерний элемент не "рулил" родителем. CSS изначально был основан на принципе наследования.

Comment: @MonkeyMutant , а мне напоминает это законы, которые сейчас пишут под безумные хотелки определённых товарищей ;-)