# Как менять задний фон при наведении на блок

Tags: html, css, hover

Как сделать так , что бы при наведении на card, менялся задний фон у four__screen ?

```css
.four__screen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
}
.font {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 720px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: red;
}
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 36px;
  width: 212px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}
.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 212px;
  height: 600px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.card:nth-child(1):hover ~ .four__screen {
  background: red;
}
.card:nth-child(2):hover ~ .four__screen {
  background: blue;
}
.card:nth-child(3):hover ~ .four__screen {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="four__screen">
            <div class="font">
               <h2>Текст</h2>
               <div class="cards">
                  <div class="card"></div>
                  <div class="card"></div>
                  <div class="card"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Вот так: `.four__screen:has(.card:hover) { background: red; }`, но сначала ознакомьтесь с [этим комментарием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504780/#comment2699077_1504780).

Comment: @ΝNL993 , еще вопрос , думал что со сменой картинке по той же аналогии делать , но почему-то не получается , вот у меня картинка с задним фоном 
`.four__screen::before {
         content: "";
         z-index: -1;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         background: url(../img/back/slide4-1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
         background-size: cover;
      }`
`.four__screen::before:has(.card:nth-child(2):hover) {  background: url(../img/back/slide4-2.jpg) no-repeat center center; }`

Comment: Потому-что before не является родителем ".card", они по сути на одном уровне находятся.

Comment: Селектор неправильный, нужен такой: `.four__screen:has(.card:nth-child(2):hover)::before`, к тому же убедитесь что у вас есть соответсвующий браузер для использования `:has`.